# Use Split String Table Value Function in a Select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table from a third party source that I have no control over. Each address field contains the FULL address including postcode. Each address has a dynamic number of separate address fields included. I have got a Split() TVF that works in splitting the address fields into seperate rows. However, when I CROSS APPLY the TVF table back to the SELECT query it returns a row for each ro in the TVF table. How do I get it to return one row for the main table and separate COLUMNS from the rows in the TVF table?

Example of addresses supplied:

a. 1 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode

b. 2 The Building, The Street, The Town, The Postcode

c. Floor 3, 3 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode

The TVF returns these as one value per row using the ',' as a delimiter. I then need to join that data back to the original data as one column per address field.

This is my SELECT QUERY:

```
select DISTINCT TOP 5 ttp.ProjectID
  ,cac.ID
  ,cac1.Proprietor1Address1
  --,CASE WHEN addr.ID = 1 THEN addr.Data END AS Address1
FROM ArdentTest.ardent.LRTitlesToProcess ttp

JOIN LandRegistryData.landreg.CommercialandCorporateOwnershipData cac
    ON ttp.TitleNo = cac.TitleNumber

JOIN (SELECT TitleNumber
            ,Proprietor1Address1
       FROM LandRegistryData.landreg.CommercialandCorporateOwnershipData
       WHERE 1 = 1
            AND ISNULL(Proprietor1Address1, '') <> '') cac1
    ON ttp.TitleNo = cac1.TitleNumber

CROSS APPLY DBAdmin.resource.Split(cac1.Proprietor1Address1, ', ') addr

WHERE 1 = 1
AND ttp.DateLRRequestSent IS NULL
AND cac.ID IN (50764, 78800, 157089, 206049, 449112)
ORDER BY 1
```

Which produces the following results:

```
ProjectID   ID      Proprietor1Address1
1010        50764   Bridge House, 1 Walnut Tree Close, Guildford, Surrey GU1 4LZ
1010        78800   Bridge House, 1 Walnut Tree Close, Guildford, Surrey GU1 4LZ
1010        157089  Bridge House, 1 Walnut Tree Close, Guildford, Surrey GU1 4LZ
1010        206049  Bridge House, 1 Walnut Tree Close, Guildford, Surrey GU1 4LZ
1010        449112  Church House, Great Smith Street, London SW1P 3AZ
```

I need to use the rows from the function to add separate address columns to the result set and I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: You cannot write a query that will return an *unknown* number of columns. Every query always produces a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their names and their types.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever except when using [dynamic pivot...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - but I would argue that is because when you're using dynamic SQL, you're constructing a *new* query to execute. Of course, that new query may have any shape you choose. It doesn't change the basic premise that any *particular* query gives results with a fixed shape.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I accept your claim. Still, a dynamic pivot can help the OP get the desired output.

Comment: I may not have been particularly clear in my original question. The use of the term DYNAMIC doesnot apply to the number of rows or columns in a table. It applies to the number of address fields contained within a SINGLE column from the external data source. I need to SPLIT this SINGLE column into different address columns to format it correctly for the database it is going into.

Comment: You should provide sample data and expected result. It doesn't have to be your data, just a minimal working example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make some assumption like an address can contain max 10 parts. You can use this script. I used STRING_SPLIT instead of your split function.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Id INT, Address VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1, '1 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode'),
(2, '2 The Building, The Street, The Town, The Postcode'),
(3, 'Floor 3, 3 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode')

SELECT * FROM @Table T
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN, * FROM STRING_SPLIT(T.Address, ','))  SRC
    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])) PVT
) X
```

Result:

```
Id          Address                                                                          1                     2                     3                     4                     5                     6                     7                     8                     9                     10
----------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
1           1 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode                   1 The Street           The Locality          The Town              The County            The Postcode         NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL
2           2 The Building, The Street, The Town, The Postcode                               2 The Building         The Street            The Town              The Postcode         NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL
3           Floor 3, 3 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode          Floor 3                3 The Street          The Locality          The Town              The County            The Postcode         NULL                  NULL                  NULL                  NULL
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is new in SQL 2016. Unfortunately we have not upgraded yet. Still on SQL 2014 :-(

Comment: I used STRING_SPLIT for test purpose, you can use your own split function instead of it.

Comment: One problem with this approach is ,that `STRING_SPLIT` does not guarantee to return the elements in the given order... There are alternatives returning the parts together with an index (e.g. Jeff Moden's `DelimitedSplit8K`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an XML out of your concatenated string and address each part via index

--the table (thx Serkan, I copied your DDL)

```sql
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Id INT, Address VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1, '1 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode'),
(2, '2 The Building, The Street, The Town, The Postcode'),
(3, 'Floor 3, 3 The Street, The Locality, The Town, The County, The Postcode');
```

--This query will return the parts one by one

```sql
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT [Address] AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AsXml
    FROM @Table
)
SELECT *
      ,AsXml.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Col1 
      ,AsXml.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Col2 
      ,AsXml.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Col3 
      ,AsXml.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)') AS Col4 
      ,AsXml.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)') AS Col5 
      ,AsXml.value('/x[6]','nvarchar(max)') AS Col6 
FROM Splitted
```

--the result

```
/*+----+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | Col1           | Col2         | Col3         | Col4         | Col5         | Col6         |
+----+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1  | 1 The Street   | The Locality | The Town     | The County   | The Postcode | NULL         |
+----+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2  | 2 The Building | The Street   | The Town     | The Postcode | NULL         | NULL         |
+----+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 3  | Floor 3        | 3 The Street | The Locality | The Town     | The County   | The Postcode |
+----+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+*/
```

--You might use `REVERSE` on all steps. This will bring the Postcode in the first place in all cases (as long as the postcode is the last element there)

```sql
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REVERSE([Address]) AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AsXml
    FROM @Table
)
SELECT *
      ,REVERSE(AsXml.value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)')) AS Col1 
      ,REVERSE(AsXml.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)')) AS Col2 
      ,REVERSE(AsXml.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)')) AS Col3 
      ,REVERSE(AsXml.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)')) AS Col4 
      ,REVERSE(AsXml.value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)')) AS Col5 
      ,REVERSE(AsXml.value('/x[6]','nvarchar(max)')) AS Col6 
FROM Splitted;
```

--the result

```
/*+----+--------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------+
| ID | Col1         | Col2       | Col3       | Col4           | Col5         | Col6    |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------+
| 1  | The Postcode | The County | The Town   | The Locality   | 1 The Street | NULL    |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------+
| 2  | The Postcode | The Town   | The Street | 2 The Building | NULL         | NULL    |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------+
| 3  | The Postcode | The County | The Town   | The Locality   | 3 The Street | Floor 3 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+----------------+--------------+---------+*/
```